# How to remove layout inflated in custom adapter

Tags: android, layout, baseadapter

```
if (audioFileList.get(position).isLastItem()) {
    convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_sound_add_button, null);
return convertView;
```

how can I catch:

```
if(convertView== R.layout.fragment_sound_add_button) { 
    remove layout, inflate new layout
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

Inside the layout file "Fragment_sound_add_button" add an id to the root.

```
//Root of fragment_sound_add_button
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/root_fragment_sound_add_button"        
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

</LinearLayout>
```

Then inside your code check if your convertView contains this Id

```
if (audioFileList.get(position).isLastItem()) {
   if(convertView.findViewById(R.id.root_fragmentn_sound_add_button) != null){ 
       //inflate the layout again
       convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_sound_add_button, null);
   } else {
      //convertView doesnt contain R.layout.fragmnt_sound_add_button
   }
   return convertView;
}
```

I hope this helps!